# Changing background-size:cover anchor from top left to top right

Tags: html, css, background

I'm creating a one page website with an image that covers the entire background (and stretches proportionally with the window). For this I'm using a "background-size: cover;"

Now, when I'm resizing the window to the smallest size it let's me, the background image seems to anchor to the default top left corner.

Is there any way for me to change the anchoring location to top right?

Comment: Sure you don't mean `background-size: cover`? You're setting the shorthand otherwise.

Comment: can't you just change the position? right:0 top: 0 ?

Comment: @ScottSelby figured it out. Added a "right top" to background

Comment: @PerfectDark Figured out a solution. Included a "right top" to background in CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try change your css code to be like this:

```
body
{
   background:#ffffff url('img_tree.png') no-repeat right top;
   margin-right:200px;
}
```

Here the demo: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background_shorthand

Comment: "right top" did it for me.
What does the margin-right:200px do?

Comment: it just does not prevent the background, try change margin-right value and you will see the changes

Comment: It doesn't respond to any margin-right edits. Design remains the same.

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/hamidmahmud/RnY36/ try change margin-right : 400px to margin-right : 200px